# Volume of solid

Tags: volume, area

Find the Volume of the solid whose cross sections perpendicular to
the $x$-axis are squares one side of which stretches from the graph of
$y = 2x + 1$ to $y = −x$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$.

Comment: I've done area and washer problems where I've integrated, but I'm really not sure what changes with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The area of a cross section selected perpendicular to the $x$-axis has volume  $\approx (2x+1 -(-x))^2 \Delta x = (3x+1)^2 \Delta x$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.